# I have 2 forms here,after submitting validatting the 1st one, how can I move to the 2nd to validate?

Tags: javascript

```
window.onload=alert("please,Sign Up first");
window.onload=pageload;

function pageload() {
    var signup=document.getElementById("signup");
    signup.onsubmit=signupp;
}

function signupp(){
    var st=document.getElementById("st").value;
    var ls=document.getElementById("ls").value;
    if (st=="First name" || st=="") {
        alert("please enter your first name");
        return false;
    }

 else if (ls=="Last name" || ls=="") {
     alert("please enter your last name");
     return false;
 }
 // what should i type here to move to loginn function ? 
}

function loginn(){
    var st=document.getElementById("st").value;
    var ls=document.getElementById("ls").value;
    if(username==""){
        alert("please enter your username or your phone number");
        return false;
    }

    if(password==""){
        alert("please enter your password");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the login wrapper div via CSS to:

```
#loginform{display:none;}
```

And then after registration set via JS to:

```
var loginform=document.getElementById("loginform");
loginform.style.display = 'block';
```